Arabic text not rendered in a DevExpress report on Android
I am using MAUI and XtraReports to print an invoice, however arabic text in the invoice is not rendered leaving only numbers and english letters. I have tried using Blazor hybrid as well but it gives the same result. It works completely fine on Windows and I am using Arial.
Windows
Android
I have installed
SkiaSharp
SkiaSharp.Views.Blazor
SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.Android 
SkiaSharp.HarfBuzz
HarfBuzzSharp.NativeAssets.Android 
DevExpress.Drawing.Skia

Yet no change. I also tried a different font but it did not change the result.
